# Determine inlined function address in dwarf

Tags: debugging, elf, dwarf

I have a virtual address (instruction pointer) of the function, obtained from [backtrace](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) call. I need to figure out the debug information about it.

For example, I need the information about `attach_backtraces` function.

```
nm -a Backtrace.so | grep attach_backtraces
000000000002cdfe t _ZN2xsL17attach_backtracesENS_3RefE
```

The offset `0x2cdfe` can be determined by substracting from PC (IP) the .so loaded address. And it matches the output from `nm`.

The following infrormation I get from `readelf -w Backtrace.so`

```
<3><3a14f>: Abbrev Number: 0
<2><3a150>: Abbrev Number: 161 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
  <3a152>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x21bf5): attach_backtraces
  <3a156>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 22
  <3a157>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 201
  <3a158>   DW_AT_decl_column : 13
  <3a159>   DW_AT_declaration : 1
  <3a159>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x3a163>
<3><3a15d>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
  <3a15e>   DW_AT_type        : <0x36aac>
<3><3a162>: Abbrev Number: 0
```

Why it's offset is `0x21bf5` and not the expected `0x2cdfe`? What a piece do I miss?  My next step would be query DWARF-info for the function at the offset `0x2cdfe` to get debug info.

PS. I'm gathering full backtrace, where symbol name, file and line should be presented. What C/C++ library are better to use to parse/get information from `DWARF` ?

Addon:

No, there are no other `attach_backtraces` in the `readelf -w` output. I have found that

DW_AT_sibling     : <0x3a163>

and it's definition:

No, there are no other `attach_backtraces` in the `readelf -w` output. I have found that

```
DW_AT_sibling     : <0x3a163>
```

and it's definition:

```
<1><3f9f5>: Abbrev Number: 27 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
   <3f9f6>   DW_AT_specification: <0x3a163>
   <3f9fa>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x2c59e
   <3fa02>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x860
   <3fa0a>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 1 byte block: 9c      (DW_OP_call_frame_cfa)
   <3fa0c>   DW_AT_GNU_all_tail_call_sites: 1
   <3fa0c>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x3fb21>
```

0x2c59e (`DW_AT_low_pc`) -  0x860 (`DW_AT_high_pc`) = 0x2cdfe (the target function address).

Is this calculation correct?

Comment: Is that function inlined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first block of DWARF dump <3a150> (where we can see offset to function name, 0x21bf5) we also see *DW_AT_declaration* flag which indicates that declaration of a function was not completed in this DIE (see section 2.13 of DWARF 5 documentation).

To find the completion of declaration you should find DIE with *DW_AT_specification* attribute, which value is a reference to DIE which it completes (as in your 2nd block, <3f9f5>) and should have in your case value <3a150>.

Taking care on mentioned above I suppose that your 2nd block is not what you want to find since it references to another DIE <0x3a163>.

When you'll find right block, then you should use DW_AT_low_pc as a parameter you need (offset to 'attach_backtraces' from process base address).

Hope this helps.

Also, from my point of view *dwarfdump* tool shows a better output than *readelf*.

Answer (score 2):

> Why it's offset is 0x21bf5 and not the expected 0x2cdfe?

The offset `0x21bf5` is the offset of the *name* of the symbol (`"attach_backtraces"` here) in the `.debug_str` section (where the names off all types, parameters, variables and functions are collected).

That offset has *absolutely no relation* to the *value* of the symbol being represented (`0x2cdfe` here). These offsets *just happened* to be close to each other to confuse you.

> What a piece do I miss?

Normally, a function should have `DW_AT_low_pc` attribute which represents its starting address (and the value of that attribute for `attach_backtraces` routine described by your output would be `0x2cdfe`).

I am not sure why you are missing `low_pc` and `high_pc` here.

One possibility is that there are actually many instances of `xs::attach_backtraces(xs::Ref)` routine (if it's declared as `inline` in a header file), and the instance that you are looking at in `readelf -w` output was discarded by the linker (the function will appear in all object files which `#include`d that header, but the linker will only keep a single instance of the function). If this is the case, look for *another* `attach_backtraces` in `readelf -w` output, with `low_pc` and `high_pc` present.